# Call another script with parameter validation

Tags: powershell

I am writing a modular script which contains a number of scripts.
so the Main Script will call another subscript and these Subscripts will sometime call other scripts as well. the calling of other scripts will be done in the same session. My problem is in the parameter validation using the ValidateScript.

So the Main Script will call another Sub-Script called NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1 and this NSX Main Script have 16 Parameter and I need to validate them in a way and if validation fails then throw back an exception.

In the below script (which is the NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1 that to be called from the Main Script) do not have all validation but I am including only validation to file path which is not working, once I get this to be working I will then add the other validations.

Whenever I call the Script from the Main script i get the below error:

```
E:\CGS-NSX-Gather-AT\NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NsxOutputFilePath'. The "If ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path)) {Throw "Provided File path for NSX Outputs ($_) is not valid."}" validation script for the argument 
with value "E:\Testing-Scripts\Test-01\" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:554
+ ... word NotUsed -NsxOutputFilePath "E:\Testing-Scripts\Test-01\" -NsxScr ...
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1
```

The Call command that I am using in the Main Script is as follow:

```
. E:\CGS-NSX-Gather-AT\CGS-NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1 -NsxManagerFqdn CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss -NsxManagerPassword VMware1! -vCenterFqdn CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -vCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -vCenterPassword VMware1! -NsxControllerPassword VMware1!VMware1! -HostingvCenterFQDN CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -HostingvCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -HostingvCenterPassword VMware1! -PrimaryNsxManagerFqdn "NotUsed" -PrimaryNsxManagerPassword NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterFqdn NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterUser NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterPassword NotUsed -NsxOutputFilePath E:\Testing-Scripts\Test-01\ -NsxScriptFilePath "E:\Testing-Scripts\Test-02"
```

The NSX-Gather-AT-Main.ps1 Script is as follow:

```
                                        #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
                                        #    ***********************************    #
                                        #           NSX-AT-Gather-Main          #
                                        #       CGS NSX Gather Assessment Tool      #
                                        #   This tool will automate the assessment  #
                                        #         process for any onboarding        #
                                        #            VMware CGS customers.          # 
                                        #    ***********************************    #
                                        #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#



################################################################################################################                                    
#PS: The code will be divided into section using the region option to better maintain/Organize of the tool code.
################################################################################################################


                #===================================================================#
                ###########      Start of Parameters of this Script       ###########
                #===================================================================#


#region 1st Section - Section-Name: ScriptParameters        
#===================================================

        #======================================#
        ###       Start of 1st Section       ###
        #======================================#

#Section Description:   This Section will hold the Parameters of this Script.
#                       PS: Parameters of this script will not be validated and the full validation will be done at a later stage of this Script through calling the NsxValidateInfo Subscript.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            NSX Manager Assessment Tool Gather Main (CGS-NSX-Gather-AT-Main) Script.
        .DESCRIPTION
            CGS-NSX-Gather-AT-Main is the main script to be called by the parent script to perform the assessment of the NSX Environment.
        .PARAMETER
            .PARAMETER NsxManagerFqdn
                Mandatory. FQDN of the NSX Manager to be assessed. Example CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss
            .PARAMETER NsxManagerPassword
                Mandatory. Admin Password of the NSX Manager to be assessed. Example VMware1!
            .PARAMETER vCenterFqdn
                Mandatory. FQDN of the vCenter server registered with the NSX Manager. Example CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
            .PARAMETER vCenterUser
                Mandatory. SSO Admin User of the vCenter server registered with the NSX Manager. Example administrator@vsphere.local
            .PARAMETER vCenterPassword
                Mandatory. SSO Admin Password of the vCenter server registered with the NSX Manager. Example VMware1!   
            .PARAMETER NsxControllerPassword
                Mandatory. Admin Password of the NSX Controllers deployed. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example VMware1! / NotUsed
            .PARAMETER HostingvCenterFQDN
                Mandatory. FQDN of the vCenter Server Hosting the NSX manager to be assessed. Example CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss
            .PARAMETER HostingvCenterUser
                Mandatory. SSO Admin User of the vCenter server Hosting the NSX manager to be assessed. Example administrator@vsphere.local
            .PARAMETER HostingvCenterPassword
                Mandatory. SSO Admin Password of the vCenter server Hosting the NSX manager to be assessed. Example VMware1!
            .PARAMETER PrimaryNsxManagerFqdn
                Mandatory. FQDN of the Primary NSX Manager if the NSX Manager to be assessed is a Secondary. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss / NotUsed
            .PARAMETER PrimaryNsxManagerPassword
                Mandatory. Admin Password of the Primary NSX Manager if the NSX Manager to be assessed is a Secondary. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example VMware1! / NotUsed    
            .PARAMETER PrimaryNsxvCenterFqdn
                Mandatory. FQDN of the vCenter server registered to the Primary NSX Manager if the NSX Manager to be assessed is a Secondary. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example CGSR-VCSA.nfv.gss / NotUsed
            .PARAMETER PrimaryNsxvCenterUser
                Mandatory. SSO Admin User of the vCenter server registered to the Primary NSX Manager if the NSX Manager to be assessed is a Secondary. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example administrator@vsphere.local / NotUsed    
            .PARAMETER PrimaryNsxvCenterPassword
                Mandatory. SSO Admin Password of the vCenter server registered to the Primary NSX Manager if the NSX Manager to be assessed is a Secondary. PS: This filed could also have a value of NotUsed. Example VMware1! / NotUsed   
            .PARAMETER NsxOutputFilePath
                Mandatory. File path for the script to dump all gathered data. Example C:\Some-File-Name.
            .PARAMETER NsxScriptFilePath
                Mandatory. File path for the script to dump all gathered data. Example C:\Some-File-Name.
        .INPUTS
            Parameters above
        .OUTPUTS
            Dumping all gathered data to the NsxOutputFilePath.
        .NOTES
            Version:        1.0
            Author:         Taher Shaker
            Creation Date:  01/11/2018
        .EXAMPLE
            .$CGS-NSX-AT-Main.ps1 -NsxManagerFqdn CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss -NsxManagerPassword VMware1! -vCenterFqdn CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -vCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -vCenterPassword VMware1! -NsxControllerPassword VMware1! -HostingvCenterFQDN CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -HostingvCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -HostingvCenterPassword VMware1! -PrimaryNsxManagerFqdn CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss -PrimaryNsxManagerPassword VMware1! -PrimaryNsxvCenterFqdn CGSR-VCSA.nfv.gss -PrimaryNsxvCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -PrimaryNsxvCenterPassword VMware1! -NsxOutputFilePath "C:\Test-Script\" -NsxScriptFilePath "C:\Test-Script\Nsx-Subscripts"
            .$CGS-NSX-AT-Main.ps1 -NsxManagerFqdn CGSM-NSX.nfv.gss -NsxManagerPassword VMware1! -vCenterFqdn CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -vCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -vCenterPassword VMware1! -NsxControllerPassword NotUsed -HostingvCenterFQDN CGSM-VCSA.nfv.gss -HostingvCenterUser administrator@vsphere.local -HostingvCenterPassword VMware1! -PrimaryNsxManagerFqdn NotUsed -PrimaryNsxManagerPassword NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterFqdn NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterUser NotUsed -PrimaryNsxvCenterPassword NotUsed -NsxOutputFilePath "C:\Test-Script\" -NsxScriptFilePath "C:\Test-Script\Nsx-Subscripts"
    #>

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    Param(

        #   1st Parameter will be the NSX Manager FQDN for the NSX Manager to be assessed.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$NsxManagerFqdn,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   2nd Parameter will be the Admin Password for the NSX Manager to be assessed.    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$NsxManagerPassword,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   3rd Parameter will be the vCenter Server FQDN for the vCenter registered with the NSX Manager to be assessed.   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$vCenterFqdn,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   4th Parameter will be the Username for the vCenter Server registered with the NSX Manager to be assessed.   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$vCenterUser,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   5th Parameter will be the Password for the vCenter Server registered with the NSX Manager to be assessed.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$vCenterPassword,

            #-----------------------------------    

        #   6th Parameter will be the Password of the NSX Controllers. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if NSX Controllers dose not exists.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$NsxControllerPassword,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   7th Parameter will be the vCenter Server FQDN for the vCenter Hosting the NSX Manager to be assessed.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$HostingvCenterFQDN,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   8th Parameter will be the Username for the vCenter Server Hosting the NSX Manager to be assessed.   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$HostingvCenterUser,

            #-----------------------------------    

        #   9th Parameter will be the Password for the vCenter Server Hosting the NSX Manager to be assessed.   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$HostingvCenterPassword,

            #-----------------------------------            

        #   10th Parameter will be the FQDN of the Primary NSX Manager. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if the NSX Manager to be assessed is not a Secondary NSX manager.            
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$PrimaryNsxManagerFqdn,

            #-----------------------------------    

        #   11th Parameter will be the Admin Password of the Primary NSX Manager. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if the NSX Manager to be assessed is not a Secondary NSX manager.          
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$PrimaryNsxManagerPassword,

            #-----------------------------------            

        #   12th Parameter will be the FQDN of the vCenter Server registered to the Primary NSX Manager. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if the NSX Manager to be assessed is not a Secondary NSX manager.   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$PrimaryNsxvCenterFqdn,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   13th Parameter will be the SSO Admin User of the vCenter Server registered to the Primary NSX Manager. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if the NSX Manager to be assessed is not a Secondary NSX manager.             
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$PrimaryNsxvCenterUser,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   14th Parameter will be the SSO Admin Password of the vCenter Server registered to the Primary NSX Manager. This Parameter could be set to NotUsed if the NSX Manager to be assessed is not a Secondary NSX manager.             
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$PrimaryNsxvCenterPassword,

            #-----------------------------------            

        #   15th Parameter will be the Path to the file where the outputs of this script will be dumped to.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({If ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path)) {Throw "Provided File path for NSX Outputs ($_) is not valid."}})]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$NsxOutputFilePath,

            #-----------------------------------

        #   16th Parameter will be the Path to the file where the NSX Subscripts and modules located.           
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({
            If ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path)) {
                Throw "Provided File path for NSX Script ($_) is not valid."
            }   
        })]     
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$NsxScriptFilePath

    ) 

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

#endregion - 1st Section - END - Section-Name: ScriptParameters

                #====================================================================
                ##############      End of Parameters of this Script    #############
                #====================================================================

    #----------------------------------------------

        #=============================================#
        ######        Start of The Script        ######
        #=============================================#
```

Comment: Add an `else{ $true }` condition to the `ValidateScript` scriptblock

Comment: Mathias, Thank you i did not know that i need to add an Else $True to the validation script, that worked as expected now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mathias R. Jessen, You need to add an Else {$True}. As I understood, when using IF condition in the validation script, then you need to make sure that at one point there would be true, so you need to add the IF and the Else to make sure that the validation would either go to $Flase or $True.

So to change the last parameter in the mentioned script it would be like the below by just adding the Else {$True}:

```
#   15th Parameter will be the Path to the file where the outputs of this script will be dumped to.
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[ValidateScript({If ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path)) {Throw "Provided File path for NSX Outputs ($_) is not valid."} Else {$True}})]
[String]$NsxOutputFilePath,

    #-----------------------------------

#   16th Parameter will be the Path to the file where the NSX Subscripts and modules located.           
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[ValidateScript({If ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path)) {Throw "Provided File path for NSX Script ($_) is not valid."}  Else {$True}})]        
[String]$NsxScriptFilePath
```